# iOS Submission issue with In-App purchase

Tags: ios, iphone, submission, in-app

I have uploaded my app with two In-App purchases. After 4 days I have received this message and the iTunes Connect status: **"Your In-App Purchase has been returned. You must modify or delete the highlighted item."**

Both of the In-App purchases are highlighted with warning sign and say **developer action needed**. Any-pointers for what the problem is (in general .. obviously specifics aren't expected)?

Sorry (DA) for being vague on the question. But So all allple say is "Converse with fellow developers and Apple engineers on technical topics.
Apple Developer Forums". So figured if anyone here had encountered this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but whatever it is, you probably need to ask Apple.

Comment: I am having the same issue! How did this turn out? Were your in-app purchases really rejected?

Comment: yeah rejected but it was this odd time when we submitted and release of iOS 6. So added a new column to be filled in and hence the error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This issue generally occurs when you fill insufficient information regarding your in app purchase .iTunes highlights your problematic area and you have to take necessary action according to that.
If your all information is right then just edit description add space after it and save it.Hope it work for you.