# Itunes Connect:In-App Purchase is getting rejected,but app was stil in review

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

The error said:Your In-App Purchase has been returned. You must modify or delete the highlighted item.
My app was alreay in review,but In-App Purchases was rejected.It seemed so strange...
I checked the highlight items,but I couldn't find any error.Is there anyone having the same problem? Or can anyone help?

Comment: Did u check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812099/ios-submission-issue-with-in-app-purchase

Comment: Yes,I had do this,but it was still getting rejected...